# PhpStorm SQL user parameters

Tags: sql, database, phpstorm

When writing a simple SQL query in PhpStorm, it won't see any Variables / Parameters,

I'm trying with different User Parameters, but nothing inside the quotes will work:

Like:

```
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);


$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" . $username . "'";
```

Or with the Single / Double quotes swapped like:

```
$query3 = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "$username"';
$query4 = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "' . $username . '"';
```

The only way it works is without quoting the variable like:

```
$query5 = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = $username';
```

But default my variables are not quoted.

The code itself works, but when running the single query from PhpStorm inline (<kbd>Ctrl + Return</kbd>) It won't ask for the parameter but just running the query with the variable name itself as value.

What do I wrong ?

Comment: You tried this aswell? `$query6 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ' . $username . '";`

Comment: Well .. my only guess that when it works (asks for a value) it sees that parameter as placeholder/variable as it's not quoted... while in all other cases the possible value is inside quotes... which means a string value (that is already provided). No proper suggestions right now.

Comment: Are you trying to use PHP inside PHPStorm? Btw. To use parameters inside PhpStorm you need to use colon, like: `where name = :name`

Comment: @boyd That's if he (OP) wants to use Prepared Statements (which he should -- safer overall/recommended). But so far his SQL queries are meant to be executed directly...

Comment: It's a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38660 . Please vote to get notified about the progress.

Comment: The mentioned issue is fixed now.